# Wine does not recognise my USB keyboard. I tried wine regedit as well. What do I do?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, keyboard, wine

My keyboard (Cosmic Byte Triton) does not have a Linux driver. To configure it properly I installed its Windows driver via Wine. But Wine is not able to detect the keyboard. The app keeps showing

> please connect the supported keyboard

Is this a solvable problem?

Is there any other macro and RGB configuring software on Linux that works for any device?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't install a driver in Wine and have it work for the rest of the Linux operating system. It doesn't really work that way.

Comment: In my experience, Wine cannot detect external devices. It is just used for software emulation (APIs translation).